# Untarring a file with limited hierarchy

Tags: tar, dash-shell

I have created a tar file in terminal. Let's say I am currently in a directory test7. I am creating a tar in my current directory of a file which is inside another directory (test8).

```
tar -czvf example.tgz ../test8/a/b
```

output:

```
example.tgz
```

Now, I untar this file using the following command :

```
tar -xzvf example.tgz
```

I get the result and a directory named as **test8** is produced.

```
$) cd test8

$) ls
-> a

$) cd a

$) ls
-> b
```

Now I can go inside the directory **b** and see my files.

I want the output to be only the directory **a** and inside of which **b** will be present i.e.
Output after untarring that I want should be of this hierarchy : 
`a/b`
But not: `test8/a/b`

Can anyone please help me out with this ?
I have been through the man page of tar but couldn't get much help from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-C` option to effectively change to the target directory

Ex. instead of

```
$ tar cvf example.tar ../Apple/Banana/Papaya
tar: Removing leading `../' from member names
../Apple/Banana/Papaya/
../Apple/Banana/Papaya/Papaya.md
```

use

```
$ tar cvf example.tar -C ../Apple Banana/Papaya
Banana/Papaya/
Banana/Papaya/Papaya.md
```

Alternatively you can remove leading directories upon extraction using the `--strip-components` option:

```
tar --strip-components=1 -xzvf example.tgz
```

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, thanks for such a quick response. The problem is that I have many other directories inside Apple directory(according to your example). But i only want to create tar of Banana/Papaya (as per your example). Can you help me out with --strip-components flag as it is not working as well.

Comment: @MazharMIK so you tried `tar -czvf example.tgz -C ../test8 a/b` and it didn't work? what happened exactly?

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, I made a small mistake. It works as expected. Thank you so much. Marking it as ACCEPTED answer